# Save the answer in PDF?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, export

Lot of answers here are excellent but there is no way to save it. Even if we can put them in favorites or print them.

> What about create a way to save answers in pdf?

Also on meta : [Is it possible to convert (and possibly download) the answers/discussions in pdf format?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/is-it-possible-to-convert-and-possibly-download-the-answers-discussions-in-pdf) but this discussion was 2 years ago and 
perhaps today is it a more feasible/interesting idea?

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/) seems to be working again. (I don't know why it was not working at the time of your comment.)

Comment: Why not simply print the page to a PDF printer?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I've tried that, and the sidebars and headers and footers are not very pleasing. Also, the page breaking is not at all done intelligently. Hopefully, an integrated approach would do better.

Comment: A related post on Meta Stack Exchange: [Printing out Stack Overflow/Exchange Q&As including comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22877)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For printing  a question together with all answers, the best option is still the same as two years ago: use **[Stack Printer](http://www.stackprinter.com/)**. There is a handy bookmarklet on that page, which allows any question to be saved as PDF directly from the question page. The quality is pretty good.

Or, if you want the Q&A to be formatted just the way you want it, try **[Save Q&A as LaTeX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16271/)**, which converts the question  with answers (and optionally, with comments) into a file that can be copy-pasted into, e.g., writeLaTeX or any other LaTeX compiler. Then get PDF from that. Some conversion errors may still occur; they require a minor manual adjustment of the source.

(I mention writeLaTeX specifically because this is the environment I use for testing the correctness of conversion in [Save Q&A as LaTeX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16271/). This project is still under development.)

---

#### Disclaimer: free version of StackEdit no longer offers saving as PDF

For saving an *individual post* (question or answer):  an improved version of the workflow suggested by  Sergio Parreiras:

1. Click to edit the question/answer.
2. Copy and paste the contents to [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/)
3. Click cancel to close the edit.
4. From the `#` menu on the left, select Save as PDF:

[image: save as pdf]

Comment: Cool. Tested on achille hui's answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838052/evaluate-int-01-prod-k-2n-lfloor-kx-rfloor-dx/851516#851516, it works perfectly well.

Comment: @Krokop That's a great post to test on... but it seems my PDF loses symbols toward the end of the post. Did you check yours toward the end? I replaced the link in the post.

Comment: Yes I check and my PDF is ok...

Comment: Hm, after several tries it worked for me too (I switched from Chrome to Firefox in the process, don't know what made the difference).

Comment: I have Firefox too so we know that works with this browser but don't know why too :).

Comment: @Krokop and thisismuchhealthier: Is it possible to make it look like a LaTeX file instead of a Word file?

Comment: I had not seen the bookmarklet before; that is quite handy. Perhaps it's been too long since I visited StackPrinter.

Comment: I have to raise awareness that saving as PDF inside Stackedit is now an option **you have to pay for**. What do ?

Comment: @G.T.R Oh no. Updated the post. I suppose this justified mentioning a related project of mine as an alternative.

Comment: Psst. @Thursday Try [this](https://stackedit-beta.herokuapp.com/#) instead of Stackedit to save money!

Comment: @GNUEmacs I got a PDF of a poor rendering quality :(

Comment: @CarlosMendoza My post lists 3 options, which one produced poor quality pdf? On which post?

Comment: I tried the free version of stackedit posted by @GNUEmacs on my answer to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1568360/specifying-difference-equation-from-hz/1569983#1569983) question, that's the one with the problem. By other hand, I also tried the Stack Printer and it does a goob job.

Comment: The dropbox link in the 'Save Q&A as LaTeX' linked post is dead.

Comment: Why doesn't Stack Edit recognize `begin{align*}`? What can I use instead?

Comment: StackEdit is pretty useless for most answers such as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3387820/finite-summation-sum-k-0n-1-csc-2-m-left-frac-pi-2-k12-ny-r/3389928#3389928

Answer (score 0):

### This answer is obsolete given the (neat!)Much healthier answer above.

It would be nice to have this feature but meanwhile, an alternative is:

1. Click to **edit** the question/answer.
2. Copy and paste the contents to your favorite $\LaTeX$ editor.
3. Click cancel to close the edit.
4. "Get a bunch of LATEX errors caused by Markdown content." (orginally from *This is Much Healthier*)
5. Use regular expressions (http://www.regular-expressions.info/) in your editor to remove/change the mark-down content.
6. Of course, it would be very nice to have a script here doing 5.

As long as you are keeping it for your personal use, I don't see why it would a problem.

Comment: 4. Get a bunch of $\LaTeX$  errors caused by Markdown content.

Comment: Put another way: MathJax is not the same as LaTeX, though it uses many LaTeX commands (among other things).

Comment: Re: step 5, see [Atwood's story](http://blog.codinghorror.com/testing-with-the-force/) about how he tried to parse a **small** subset of Markdown (mini-Markdown, used in comments) with regular expressions. This one was just to handle single asterisks: `(?<=[s^,(])*(?=S)(.+?)(?<=S)*(?=[s$,.?!])` And it was still buggy. After Atwood left, SE developers eventually rewrote the mini-Markdown code from scratch (I think). Parsing all of Markdown syntax would be of orders of magnitude more complicated.

Comment: One more thing: "user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required", so one can do much more with the content than just keep it for personal use.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. For example one can print it as a rug and give mathematical answers to people, so they can feel they walk all over mathematics every day! Or as a set of clothes... One could even tattoo answers on their arms (useful for exams).

Comment: Or write one's name at the top and hand in as homework.

Comment: @WillJagy But... **attribution required**. As long as the URL is there, that's okay though.