# Saving MathJax file drafts

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax, export

Questions/answers are available here on line. However how do we save them in a separate MathJax directory to read them later off line?

Comment: Related question: [How can MathJax be used offline?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10394/how-can-mathjax-be-used-offline)

Comment: If you want just read the posts (and not edit them), you can have a look at suggestion in this post and related posts: [Save the answer in PDF?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15163/save-the-answer-in-pdf)

Comment: [Stack Exchange data dumps](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackexchange_archive.torrent) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

MathJax, being a JavaScript program, is meant to be executed in a web browser. For offline use it is more natural to use standalone programs. Two of the options are:

1. [Save as PDF](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15163/save-the-answer-in-pdf) and later view using  a [PDF viewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software).
2. [Save as TeX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15230/147263) and later edit and compile using a [TeX editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors).

The first option is simpler, but the second one allows you to optimize formatting for your viewing needs.