# Problem exporting an answer to pdf

Tags: support, mathjax, export

MSE offers a huge variety of possibilities when it comes to writing an answer/question which might not be found elsewhere (at least all together).

I've recently read on [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15163/save-the-answer-in-pdf) post, that answers can be exported to pdf with StackEdit - which is a great opportunity.

However, when I copy&paste an answer I want to download, StackEdit doesn't recognize `\begin{align*}`  and claims

> KaTeX parse error: No such environment: align* at position [...]

What can I do? Are there any alternatives for StackEdit or for `begin{align*}`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some time back StackEdit veered away from `MathJax` support for $\LaTeX$ and instead took up [the KaTeX package](https://katex.org/).  Presently they support fewer "environments" than are provided here under `MathJax`.

A workaround for the particular deficiency you found is to use `\begin{aligned}` and `\end{aligned}` rather than the (unsupported by StackEdit) `align*` environment.

Comment: I just checked and both of the following worked:

`$$\begin{align} ... \end{align}$$`

and

`$$\begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned}$$`

It doesn't need to be all in one line, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on @hardmath's answer (I would edit it, but `Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites.`):

In [stackedit.io](https://stackedit.io)

#### `$$\begin{align} ... \end{align}$$` displays with numbered annotations

```
$$
\begin{align}
(a + b)(a + b) &= a^2 + ab + ab + b^2 \\
&= a^2 + 2ab + b^2
\end{align}
$$
```

displays with numbered annotations like this:

$$
\begin{align}
(a + b)(a + b) &= a^2 + ab + ab + b^2 &&(1)\\
&= a^2 + 2ab + b^2 &&(2)
\end{align}
$$

#### `$$\begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned}$$` displays without annotations

```
$$
\begin{aligned}
(a + b)(a + b) &= a^2 + ab + ab + b^2 \\
&= a^2 + 2ab + b^2
\end{aligned}
$$
```

displays without annotations like this:

$$
\begin{aligned}
(a + b)(a + b) &= a^2 + ab + ab + b^2 \\
&= a^2 + 2ab + b^2
\end{aligned}
$$