# Side by side editor that supports LaTex or Mathjax or similar **and** Markdown?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, markdown, editor

Writing and editing long entries in stackexchange can be cumbersome. I recently found [stackedit.io](https://stackedit.io) which is great way to write and edit the longer entries. It has:

- side by side editor/preview
- Markdown support (via Pagedown)
- Katex support (e.g. `$` and `$$`)

However, it's lacking one thing: support for LaTex things such as:

```
\begin{align}
...
\end{align}
```

Comment: As I had occasion to [point out previously](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30220/3111), StackEdit supports `\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}`.  It has been close enough for my *wysiwyg* needs.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried it out and it didn't work -- at least I didn't see it in the preview -- maybe it works when existing to pdf? But I'm trying to get it to work for preview.

Comment: No it doesn't have anything to do with PDF export.  Thanks for trying.  I just checked one of my existing files there and it works for me (in the displaystyle `$$....$$` environment).

Comment: Gotcha. It worked like that and so did `$$\begin{align} ... \end{align}$$`.