# Defining New Commands Renders As Empty Space

Tags: support, mathjax, newcommand

How do I define new commands at the top without creating multiple spaces before the first character?
[image]

Also, is it just my browser, or is the rendering engine on StackExchange much slower than on StackEdit?

#### EDIT

This is better but still creates a single space.
[image]

Comment: It's better to put these commands where you need them, because otherwise they interfere with the preview text and Google search results anyway.

Comment: It's going to be a long post where I need the commands pretty often :D  I could write it in some other editor and then replace them inline before posting.

Comment: Or, as I suggested, define them when they are needed and not before.

Comment: Yes, but for editing a long post this makes the source code super confusing.

Comment: What do you mean that it can interfere with preview text?  It seems to work fine, but could there be complications in the future?  Is StackExchange moving to KaTeX just like StackEdit?  Because this would break it, unless they fix it until then...

Comment: Re: *preview text*. If you see some [list of questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monads), the beginning of the text is displayed. This is based on constant number of characters - in some cases, this might mostly be the definitions of macros.

Comment: Regarding the "rendering engine on StackExchange" vs. StackEdit, it has been [discussed before](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30220/3111) that benweet (author of StackEdit) chose Katex rather than MathJax some years ago for a performance advantage. I use StackEdit in-browser (Chrome/Chromium), but it might be that the stand-alone version of StackEdit (3+ years old at this point) may provide additional speed over the baseline of StackExchange in browser.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work.  It's a bit ugly, but still.
[image]