# Print to PDF too narrow

Tags: support, feature-request, bug, status-completed, export

I am using Chrome (74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit)) and trying to print a question (specifically this one [Assistance with proof of $(AB)^T=B^T A^T$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440305/assistance-with-proof-of-abt-bt-at)) to "Save as PDF".

The content is printed as a narrow column on the left of the page (see the picture, if I attached it right).

Can I fix this to print right?

[image: Screenshot of PDF]

Comment: If it helps as a workaround, you might have a look at the suggestions here: [Save the answer in PDF?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15163) and [Printing out Stack Overflow/Exchange Q&As including comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22877) Probably a reasonable solution might be using [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/).

Comment: Make sure you disable responsiveness.

Comment: These posts on Meta Stack Exchange might be related to this specific issue: [A possible bug: The right margin of printed SE content is way too large](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326967) and [CSS bug with printing site pages (now with 100% more suggested fix included!)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317013).

Answer (score 2):

This is completed as per https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329187/235711